# Do I paginate API data on the client or the server?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express

I am currently working on an project where I use an API's client credentials flow in order to retrieve data. I am able to get a response with an access token and grab data, but there is a limit and I have to paginate in order to get all of the data I am looking for. Right now I am stuck on a design problem.

Should I get the access token by server and find a way to pass it to client? And then from the client I can do requests in order to get data and paginate? I think this is much easier doing so on React (client) than doing it on Express (server), but I am worried that passing over access tokens over to the client every time the page loads might be inefficient because I'd have to authenticate every time. Should I store the access token to local storage?

The other way is paginating through Express, but it seems much more difficult to program that out and I am puzzled on which way is the right way to do it. Could someone please provide me some insight? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Doesn't matter you do api call for pagination or any api call, you should pass access token to server to authenticate yourself, that is how the access token is deigned for.

   - Login in with username and password
   - The server check if username and password are valid then generate access token with some information such as username, userId, role, expiration.. then send to client (React, React-Native...)
   - If server store access token in cookies for web client, you don't need to do anything, any following request will include token in cookie automatically, if client is mobile, you need to store token somewhere in mobile (asyncStorage for RN), then every following request you need to send access token along with the request data to server on the way server tells you do.
   - The server can authenticate you base on the token and send data or error back based on the validity.
2. If you do pagination you need to have another token called continue token, it includes the limit of data, last itemId you got from previous api call...

   - Server will authenticate client based on access token as I mention above
   - If you'r authenticated, server will decode the token and get information then query database and send data back to client